# Remove NumberPicker arrows Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to remove the `NumberPicker` UP/DOWN arrows?

I googled but I wasn't able to find any method.. I have 2 devices one with android 4.2.2 and one with 4.0.3, in the first one the `NumberPicker` is scrollable and has no arrows while in the second one the `NumberPicker` isn't scrollable and has the up/down arrows

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html. Read the docs carefully

Comment: @Raghunandan What I get with 3 different devices (2.3.3, 4.0.3, 4.2.2) are 3 different styles of number picker, I just want the 4.0.3 to be the same as the one used by the 4.2.2, and since they use the same theme I can't understand why they're different

Comment: Read the documentation??

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the android documentation class overview:

In your older device you get this one.

> If the current theme is derived from Theme the widget presents the current value as an editable input field with an increment button above and a decrement button below. Long pressing the buttons allows for a quick change of the current value. Tapping on the input field allows to type in a desired value.

Whereas what you desire is this flavour of the widget:

> If the current theme is derived from Theme_Holo or Theme_Holo_Light the widget presents the current value as an editable input field with a lesser value above and a greater value below. Tapping on the lesser or greater value selects it by animating the number axis up or down to make the chosen value current. Flinging up or down allows for multiple increments or decrements of the current value. Long pressing on the lesser and greater values also allows for a quick change of the current value. Tapping on the current value allows to type in a desired value.

This would seem to be from a compatibility issue due to android version. Check what minimum version of android your Holo derived themes use in your app. It may be that the theme your older 4.* device is not accessing the same theme, but one that shares many similarities.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should create your own number picker and [inflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) it.
You can follow [this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-ui-inflate-from-xml-dynamic-ui.html) tutorial on inflating elements .